# show related message to input

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

this is my codes, how can i display related error message to input
i used array for name of input `name="name_fa[]"`, i did like this but its doesnt work

```
  <input type="text" value="{{ old('name_fa.'.$key) }}" name="name_fa[]" id="" class="form-control">
            @if ($errors->has('name_fa.'.$key))
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('name_fa.'.$key)}}</strong>
            </div>
            @endif
```

print_r $errors

```
  Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object
(
    [bags:protected] => Array
        (
            [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object
                (
                    [messages:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [name_fa.0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => فیلد name_fa.0 الزامی است
                                )

                            [name_fa.1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => فیلد name_fa.1 الزامی است
                                )
                            ,
                           ...
```

Comment: what is the key?

Comment: it is array loop index. 0.. 1, ...

Comment: check `print_r($errors)`

Comment: @ZainFarooq i post errors in my question can you please check it

Comment: Do you have any value stored in the `$key`?

Comment: Sorry but add `dd($errors)` to get it in the more simplified form

Answer (score 0):

The validator errors are related to the inputs names : it does not validate your input array sub-elements. So the errors are only for your "input name".

Therefore you cannot target the "name_fa" sub elements. You can get `$errors->first('name_fa')` but can not get `$errors->first('name_fa.'.$key)`